# Calling a method from parent class that has a different name in the subclass

Tags: python, oop

Having the following code:

```
class Point:
    'class that represents a point in the plane'

    def __init__(self, xcoord=0, ycoord=0):
        ''' (Point,number, number) -> None
        initialize point coordinates to (xcoord, ycoord)'''
        self.x = xcoord
        self.y = ycoord

    def setx(self, xcoord):
        ''' (Point,number)->None
        Sets x coordinate of point to xcoord'''
        self.x = xcoord

    def sety(self, ycoord):
        ''' (Point,number)->None
        Sets y coordinate of point to ycoord'''
        self.y = ycoord

    def get(self):
        '''(Point)->tuple
        Returns a tuple with x and y coordinates of the point'''
        return (self.x, self.y)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        '''(Point,number,number)->None
        changes the x and y coordinates by dx and dy'''
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

    def __repr__(self):
        '''(Point)->str
        Returns canonical string representation Point(x, y)'''
        return 'Point('+str(self.x)+','+str(self.y)+')'

class Rectangle(Point):
    def __init__(self,bottom_left,top_right,color):
        self.get = bottom_left 
        self.get = top_right
        self.color = color
    def get_bottom_left(self,bottom_left):
        print ()

r1 = Rectangle(Point(0,0), Point(1,1), "red")
r1.get_bottom_left()
```

I want to be able to print "Point(0,0)" by calling self__rep__(self) from class Point from the method get_bottom_left, but I just have no idea how. I know how to use inheritance if the functions have the same name, but in this case I am stuck and it is a requirement for the child function to have the method names it has. If it looks that I am just looking for the answer, I would like the response to just explain me a similar case of this application please!

When I do the following:

```
class Rectangle(Point):
    def __init__(self,bottom_left,top_right,color):
        self.get = bottom_left 
        self.get = top_right
        self.color = color
    def get_bottom_left(self,bottom_left):
        print (self.bottom_left)
```

I get: get_bottom_left() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bottom_left'

Comment: There are some bigger issues here, I think, the largest of which being that `Rectangle` should not inherit from `Point`. Rather an instance of `Rectangle` should *contain* several instances of `Point`.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, Rectangle should contain Point instances and not inherit Point. If you change Rectangle class as shown below, you'll see the expected result:

```
class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self, bottom_left, top_right, color):
        self.bottom_left = bottom_left 
        self.top_right = top_right
        self.color = color

    def get_bottom_left(self):
        print self.bottom_left
```